# The localisation of the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ at the prime ideal $(p)$ is PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $p$ is prime number, prove that
$$\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}=\left\{\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{Q}: \text{$p$ doesn't divide $b$}\right\}$$
is a PID.

So, first step is to show that $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is an Ideal Domain and then show that every ideal in it is principal.

I know that $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is the subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ then it follows that $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is commutative. Then I'm lost what to do. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Try to think a little bit backwards: You know that if there is only one maximal ideal, such ideal contains exactly those element that are not invertible. Do you know which kind of fractions in $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ are not invertible?

Comment: How is "$p$ doesn't divide $n$" a property of $\frac ab$? There are not even any variables in common. So what you're defining is either all of $\mathbb Q$ or the empty set, depending on whether $p$ divides $n$ or not.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You are right, I was suggesting help without even noticing this!

Comment: @Henning, Sorry I have edited the question. It's $p$ doesn't divide $b$

Comment: @Wore, elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ which is not invertible is the fractions where the numerator is the multiple of $p$

Comment: @Dietrich, I don't know what is DVR

Comment: Do you know the characterization of ideals of a localization? These have the form $I_{(p)}$ where $I$ is an ideal of $\Bbb{Z}$ disjoint from $\Bbb{Z} \setminus (p)$ (i.e. contained in $(p)$). In particular, since $\Bbb{Z}$ is a PID, every ideal is generated by one element, and the same holds for $\Bbb{Z}_{(p)}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: That's not really the same question. The ring is the same, but the property being proved about it is different.

Comment: @ElQanas Exactly, so $\mathcal{M}=p\cdot \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ will be the unique maximal ideal (and, you can prove it by showing that any other element is invertible). To show that $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is a PID, you can show that if $I$ a proper ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, then $I=\langle x\rangle $ where $x$ has the form $x=p^{k}\frac{a}{b}$, and $k=\min\{n\in\mathbb{N}: \text{$p^n$ divides some element in $I$}\}$

Comment: @Dietrich, I have no DVR in my lecture note so I think I can prove it with the more calssical way

Comment: @ElQanas OK, then you can use the duplicate to see that $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is a local ring, and the comment by Wore to obtain PID.

Comment: @Wore, hang on. Is 1 in $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$? Because $1=p/p$ is not in $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ but if $1=n/n$ where n not prime then 1 is in $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$. I'm confused

Comment: @ElQanas Well, technically $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}=\{\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{Q}: \gcd(a,b)=1, \text{and $p$ does not divide $p$}\}$, that is, you are supposed to "reduce the fraction" before deciding if it is an element of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ or not. So, $1\in\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, and in fact you have that $\mathbb{Z}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}\subseteq \mathbb{Q}$. I add some examples: $1,2,p,p+1\in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, if $p\neq 3$ then $\frac{2}{3}p\in\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$, and $\frac{1}{2p}\not\in\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$.

Comment: @Wore, Oh I understand. Thanks so much! :)